# How connect to existing MSSQL database on server from local computer with .net core 3 library Project

Tags: orm, dbcontext, ef-database-first, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to connect to SQL Server in a .NET Core 3 library, for implementation this ORM I use "Database First Scaffold-DbContext" command like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=IP/sql2016;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
    Persist Security Info=True; User ID=UserName; Password=Password; 
    MultipleActiveResultSets=False; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; 
    Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir 
    Models -Force
```

If I use this command with IP server, it just creates `DbContext` and does not create table models. If I replace the server IP with local (when restore database backup to my local database) it creates all data models.

I don't know what should I do?

Another question: when I create a data model, does it not assign primary key to my model?

Answer (score 1):

My database user was not db owner so it can't create models.